# javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException error in linux

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have a music in my jar application. When i run jar file in windows, to play the sound is well but when i run jar file in suse (VMWare) to play the sound has error.
The error is :

```
Error with playing sound.
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_UNSIGNED 11025.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
at com.kit.vip.popup.MainFrame.playSound(MainFrame.java:111)
at com.kit.vip.popup.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:97)
at com.kit.vip.popup.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:95)
```

I change bitrate of my sound to 40K. now sound paly with below command but the sound is very weak.

> aplay test.wav
>   Playing WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono

I don't know what is my problem and how can i solve this. Please suggest a way. Thanks

Comment: Is this an application you have written? From the error it does say `PCM_UNSIGNED 11025.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  *not supported.*`

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes i wrote this program. How can solve this? what is your suggestion? I use another format?

Comment: The only format I have experience with is 44100 fps, 16-bit, stereo, little-endian, aka "CD" quality. I think it is one of the most commonly supported formats. It may create files that are too large for your application, but it could be useful for testing purposes.